# How to split a vector into smaller vectors in a loop?

Tags: r

I have a list of 1253 strings in R.

```
EMT
"1", "2", "3", ..., "1252", "1253"
```

I want to split it into almost equal parts to have ~100 values in each sublist.

I was able to do split with this

```
split(EMT, rep(1:13))
```

It splits my list. But I think I need to assign those sublists to variables to be able to use them for further analysis.

My desired output is

```
EMT1
"1", "2", ..., "96"

EMT2
"97", "98", ..., "192"
...
EMT13
"1157", ..., "1253"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will this work:

```
EMT <- list(1:1253)
EMT <- sapply(EMT, as.character)
mylist <- split(EMT, rep(1:13))
names(mylist) <- lapply(names(mylist), function(x) paste0('EMT',x))
names(mylist)
 [1] "EMT1"  "EMT2"  "EMT3"  "EMT4"  "EMT5"  "EMT6"  "EMT7"  "EMT8"  "EMT9"  "EMT10" "EMT11" "EMT12" "EMT13"
 list2env(mylist, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: thank you. I applied this to my data, but when I try to call any sublist (EMT13) I get an error "object EMT13 not found"

Comment: @YuliaKentieva, have updated my answer, you need to give "list2env(mylist, .GlobalEnv)" so that list elements are saved in global environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can create groups of 96 elements each and split the data into list.

```
EMT <- as.character(1:1253)
list_data <- split(EMT, paste0('EMT', ceiling(seq_along(EMT)/96)))
```

Usually, it is better to keep data in a list instead of having lot of variables in global environment however, if you still want them as separate objects use `list2env`.

```
list2env(list_data, .GlobalEnv)
```